# Mac OS X Git self assigned SSL certificate issue

Tags: git, osx-mavericks, git-svn, atlassian-sourcetree

I want to clone project form GIT repository which has self assigned SSL certificate. Source tree client under Mac OS says the server requires certificate. Console says fatal error unable to access "Server URL":  Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to {Server URL}:-9824[image]

I don't know how the server is configured, but there is some transformation between svn-git. I have cert.p12 file. I've tried to import it in KeyChain, but it is still not working.
It is even not saying that the cert is not trusted.

Does someone have idea what is the problem?